# lambda brainfuck and virtual machines

Tags: discussion

I've been playing with some ideas for a challenge to poke fun at java virtual machines and was pondering a brainfuck virtual machine (three bit bus!) and I got to wondering if there are any brainfuck variants that support closures, function calls, and function references.

Answer (score 3):

You could be interested in [Brainfuct](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfunct). It's Brainfuck, but with lambdas, and great functional programming features. For example, in Brainfuct, the cat program looks like this.

```
>,.<@/+@
```

In this program, two functions are declared, main function (`+@`), and first function (`>,.<@`). `@` calls the function under pointer. As you can see, there is lambda (functions can read state - i.e. tape), function calls (`@`), and function references (every function (with exception for main function) is a number).

Comment: So we have two out of three, function calls and function references, but not closures.

Comment: @hildred: What is your definition of closure? This is Brainfuck, not language with local variables. There is just tape - and you can access it.